# Where does Android store offline contacts and email account details?

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts, sync, email, stock-email-app

Basically, I want to set up a home-rolled sync for these, but I have no idea where they live by default on a CyanogenMod without GApps. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Check if its present in `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db` ? You may need a [SQL manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager) to take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email accounts are saved in the the file `accounts.db` under `/data/system/users/<userId>/`. If you're the primary user, then the `userId` should be `0`.

You can also consider taking the accounts' backup using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).

Offline contacts are handled by **Contacts Storage** (`com.android.providers.contacts`) app and the contacts are stored in its data directory under the file `contacts2.db`. Your profile details are stored in the file `profile.db`. Both files are at the location `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/`. I recommend backing up both.

You can consider Titanium Backup again if you want to backup **Contacts Storage** app or simply the contacts which it allows you to export using its menu. Although the **Contacts** app allows exporting natively  all the contacts into a VCF file.